# Is merge in PowerBi only apply on current dataset or will that effect on future data?

Tags: powerbi, report

So i have 2 dataset, lets say table A and table B.
Table A always has new data come in and it associate with a date column.
Table B is a fact table and its temporary wont change.
So, i need to create a visual and i need data from both table, so i decide to merge both table on PowerBI.
My question is if i merge the current data and next day if new data coming into table A, will it also have the data from table B?
(depend on the complex of my table, so the i dont want to do it on sql side)
Here is the example for this question

Table A

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1/1 |
| 2 | Banana | 1/1 |

Table B

| ID | Name | Something |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | aaaa |
| 2 | Banana | bbbb |

the result i want to see on my report

| ID | Name | Date | Something |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1/1 | aaaa |
| 2 | Banana | 1/1 | bbbb |

and next day table A has some new records(yes, it will have duplicate record)

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Banana | 1/2 |
| 1 | Apple | 1/2 |
| 1 | Apple | 1/1 |
| 2 | Banana | 1/1 |

Will i get?

| ID | Name | Date | Something |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Banada | 1/2 | bbbb |
| 1 | Apple | 1/2 | aaaa |
| 1 | Apple | 1/1 | aaaa |
| 2 | Banana | 1/1 | bbbb |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. When you refresh, the new data will follow your merge or relationship rules.